# PHP extracting zip archives with cyrillic filenames

Tags: php, encoding, zip

Hello) I have the following problem:

My php app has to upload zip archive to the server and then show its content. Everything works fine, but when the zip archive contains files with cyrillic names, they show incorrectly.

For example, I upload zip archive with the file named фыфыфы.doc.

I open it in php next way:

```
$path = $_FILES['file-0']['tmp_name'];
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($path);

$fileName = $zip->getNameIndex(0);
```

And when I print a $fileName, I get the next:

ΣδΣδΣδ.doc

What should I do to get the correct original filename in PHP?